# Unable to install VLC

Tags: software-installation, vlc

This is what happens:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc
```

Please help. I would also like to know when this error occurs, I've seen it before too.

Comment: Which Ubuntu Version You Are Running?

Comment: he is using 13.10 :+

Comment: Be sure to enable `universe` repository from `Software and Updates`

Comment: Visit [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481354)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open a Terminal an type the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Vlc was not found because it's only available in the [universe repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/vlc).