# Unable to locate package

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, software-installation

There are many [questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=unable%20to%20locate%20package) about `Unable to locate package`.

For example : if user try to install `package` by using `apt-get` then the following error shown. (Here `package` is used only as example for displaying error message):

```
sudo apt-get install package
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package package
```

What does this error mean? How do I solve it?

[**Here**](https://askubuntu.com/a/481355/256099) provided General solution to understand and how to solve such type of error (which is helpful for new users that may unaware of repository-apt install mechanism)

*Note* : For resolving unmet-dependencies, visit: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246/256099).