# Add packages to the LiveCD when using Ubuntu Customization Kit

Tags: package-management, uck

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to create my own customized Live CD. I chose to use the Ubuntu Customization Kit, which I added as a package to my Ubuntu install on my Hard Disk. Now I would like to add some packages to the LiveCD. When attempting to use the Customization Kit, I get the question:
`Would you like to continue building, or use the console?`

If I choose "Continue building" the iso file gets created and I have no option to include the extra packages I want. If I choose to use the console, no package manager starts.

There is no "Run package manager" option available.

[image]

If I enter

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

the console outputs:

> E: Unable to locate package vlc

I also tried to install the Synaptic Package Manager but the program uses my installation of Ubuntu instead the one of the live CD. Then I tried to use File > Save Marking As ... and saved the file under `~/tmp/remaster-root`. Afterwards I tried to copy the cached packages with the built in file explorer from the local installation to the live CD (`~/tmp/remaster-root/var/cache/apt/archives/`) but the files aren't copied. The whole thing is in a VMware but it should make no difference. I also tried it with the console

```
cp -a /var/cache/apt/archives/* ~/tmp/remaster-root/var/cache/apt/archives
```

> cp: target '/home/anonymous/tmp/remaster-root/var/cache/apt/archives'
>   is not a directory

How do I integrate packages like VLC, Truecrypt or TBB into the LiveCD?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! The error you are getting appears to be self-explanatory. `/home/anonymous/tmp/remaster-root/var/cache/apt/archives` is not a directory. see `man mkdir`

Comment: I think I have a problem with the root directory. If I copy the path into the file explorer the path can be opened without a problem. In the terminal there is no `tmp` directory. I think I'm missing some knowledge of the concept in shell commands and directories ...

Comment: Your problem is more likely associated with `~` being shorthand for `/home/anonymous`

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I don't know how to solve the copy problem. Could you give me another hint?

Comment: `cp -a /var/cache/apt/archives/* ~/tmp/remaster-root/var/cache/apt/archives` quite literally means `cp -a /var/cache/apt/archives/* /home/anonymous/tmp/remaster-root/var/cache/apt/archives` when you are logged in as user `anonymous`. You may be intending to copy to /tmp/remaster-root/var/cache/apt/archives. I've never used UCK but the error seems clear.

Comment: I tried it with your command but it still doesn't work. In this tmp folder there aren't the files generated by UCK. What I don't get is that the program Files 3.10.1 shows me under Home > tmp the folder where I want to copy the files. Also under Computer > home/anonymous/tmp/ there are the files. How can I access the files within the terminal? There is some difference here ... Or UCK does generate some temporary folders here which can only accessed by Files. The copy & paste in Files doesn't work here. Strange.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/739139-roll-your-own-customized-ubuntu-with-uck

Comment: Also see this regarding `E: Unable to locate package` errors. http://askubuntu.com/questions/481354/how-to-solve-unable-to-locate-package-error/481355#481355

Answer (score 1):

Select console application from your prompt and then when it appears run

```
echo -e "\ndeb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe\ndeb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse\n" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

to set apt-get sources and then

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: Is this version specific, or the sources.list file downloaded will work for any version?