# Uninstalled vim, now can't install it again

Tags: 14.04, apt, vim, vi

I have removeded vim-tiny to get full installation following this [tutorial](http://docs.oseems.com/general/operatingsystem/ubuntu/install-vim)
and now I can't install vim by:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package vim is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'vim' has no installation candidate
```

If I simply try to install vim-tiny again situation is same:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-tiny
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package vim-tiny is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'vim-tiny' has no installation candidate
```

Output of `vim -version` is:

```
$ vim -version
The program 'vim' can be found in the following packages:
 * vim
 * vim-gnome
 * vim-tiny
 * vim-athena (You will have to enable component called 'universe')
 * vim-gtk (You will have to enable component called 'universe')
 * vim-nox (You will have to enable component called 'universe')
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I have also tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and it's all the same. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It is very strange situation for me to perform `sudo apt-get remove vim-tiny` but can't perform `sudo apt-get install vim-tiny` after this.
Any help?

Comment: Yes. It was an issue. I forgot I'm disable these repos when there was down few days ago. Thank you. Post the answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`vim`** is available on [main repository](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/main/base/vim) of Ubuntu.

> The **main** component contains applications that are free software, can be freely redistributed and are fully supported by the Ubuntu team. & The **universe** component is a snapshot of the free, open-source, and Linux world.

So, First enable Main & Universe repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe"
```

Then installed packages by following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Following is helpful for more(visit for unmet-dependencies and unable-to-locate-package):

- [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246)
- [Unable to locate package](https://askubuntu.com/q/481354/256099)