# Unable to locate package libffi and libffi5-dev on Ubuntu 12.04.4 through apt-get

Tags: 12.04, shared-library, wunderlist

```
$ sudo apt-get install libffi libffi5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libffi
E: Unable to locate package libffi5-dev
```

another try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libffi5 libffi-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libffi5
```

and

```
$ cat /etc/issue  
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS \n \l
```

What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to locate package](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481354/unable-to-locate-package)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The packages are be called `libffi6` and `libffi-dev`.

Package names can be searched on http://packages.ubuntu.com/

---

For searching packages use `apt-cache search`.
Example in your case following can help you:

```
$ apt-cache search libffi
libffi-dev - Foreign Function Interface library (development files)
libffi6 - Foreign Function Interface library runtime
libffi6-dbg - Foreign Function Interface library runtime (debug symbols)
ffindex-dbg - simple index/database for huge amounts of small files (debug)
libbfio-dbg - Library to provide basic input/output abstraction (debug)
libffindex0 - library for simple index/database for huge amounts of small files
libffindex0-dev - library for simple index/database for huge amounts of small files (development)
libjffi-java - Java Foreign Function Interface
libjffi-jni - Java Foreign Function Interface (JNI library)
```

Comment: @Jan Edited (Improved) your answer by providing `apt-cache search`.

Comment: libffi5 and libffi6 aren't the same thing. For example when downloading and running pypy3 on raspbian, I will still get "error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

You can also try installing the upstream Debian `libffi5` package, if another package specifically requires `libffi5`.

See: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libffi5 or the appropriate upstream Debian version for your Ubuntu release.

Download the appropriate Debian package (`.deb`) for your architecture, and install using `dpkg`; e.g. `dpkg -i libffi5_3.0.10-3+deb7u2_amd64.deb`. Then either fix the original install (`apt-get -f install`), or reinstall the desired package (`apt-get install ...`).

Comment: For that matter, you could manually install the [package from Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libffi6), although it no longer has libffi5 there.

Answer (score 1):

Your Ubuntu package repository may be too old to update.

Keep in mind select the suitable architecture and change your package repository url by adding a line to your **/etc/apt/sources.list** like this:

```
deb https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.enzu.com-archive focal main
```

There are alternative [other mirror links](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)  like  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.enzu.com-archive.

Select the suitable mirror based on your region and internet speed.

or you can download the package directly and install it.