# unable to find mysql-server package in ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management

I tried installing mysql using the command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

then after entering the password, I'm getting the message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server
```

Why is this happening, and how can I solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to locate package](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481354/unable-to-locate-package)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages by apt](http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt)

Answer (score 8):

Apart from depeneding on the Repository source. You can try following

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then search for the package using apt-cache.

```
sudo apt-cache search mysql | grep mysql | more
```

You will have couple of results and you can choose appropriate one for you. You might need the client or Server (depends on your needs). The result is as below:

```
    mysql-server - MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
    mysql-server-5.5 - MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
    mysql-client - MySQL database client (metapackage depending on the latest version)
mysql-server - MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
 mysql-client-5.5 - MySQL database client binaries
```

Once you figure out what version of sql is available. You can install it with apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Hope this helps. Alos this is the [official Mysql Community page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/) to download MySQL Server for different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The package name it will install is `mysql-server-5.6` (the digits are there so you could also install another version; like 5.5). So you can also use ...

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

I would suggest to update your system if not updated and to check the repositories you have active.

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
[sudo] password: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.19.0-15 linux-headers-3.19.0-15-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-15-generic linux-image-3.19.0-7-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-15-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-7-generic
```

`mysql-server` should be present on any Ubuntu system by default.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `sources.list` file correct?

By the way; you can install deb package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and install it using `dpkg -i PACKAGENAME`. For ubunut 14.04 you can download it from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mysql-server).